# Creating mysql dockerfile from previous docker-compose set-up

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Previously, my database container was initialized with docker-compose.
Since I'm moving to AWS, I want to place it in a Dockerfile. This is apparently not as straightforward as I thought. How can I do this?

**Docker-compose**

```
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: camunda_mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_USER=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=camunda_db
    volumes:
      - MyDataVolume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  MyDataVolume:
```

This is something I found online, but I can't get it to work:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
RUN ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client mysql-server
RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]
```

**startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ ! -f /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 ]; then
    mysql_install_db

    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
    sleep 10s

    echo "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO USERNAME@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql

    killall mysqld
    sleep 10s
fi

/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use the same `mysql:latest` Docker image? Also, what is the error?

Comment: there's no error, but nothing is running on port 3306. Also, maybe I could. I've never used a seperate file for a mysql container, so I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: You shoud definitely use it. See [the official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). There is, from what I understand of your situation, no use to recreate everything from scratch.

Comment: Yes I managed to get it working, I was looking at it the wrong way. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I just can't see the relation between docker-compose file and Dockerfile, because docker-compose file is about starting and managing services (just like docker create service ...) and Dockerfile is about building images!

Comment: Yes I misinterpreted it a bit I guess.